# simple form validation in dancer/perl

Tags: perl, dancer

I am trying to do a simple form validation  in perl dancer  but I was wondering what would be the best way to validate simple parameters (e.g. field cannot be empty, validity of the email, minimum length of a field) in dancer/perl without any extra plugin or CPAN module

here is the code so far

```
post '/register' => sub {

my $db = connect_db();
my $sql = 'insert into users (username, email, password, motivation) values (?, ?, ? ,?)';
my $sth = $db->prepare($sql) or die $db->errstr;
$sth->execute(params->{'username'}, params->{'email'},params->{'password'}, params->{'motivation'}) or die $sth->errstr;

set_flash('Hey you signed up !');
redirect '/thanks';
};
```

I did google it and I found several ways to do validation using CPAN modules like Form::Foo but how do it without that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to expressly avoid using a plugin or a CPAN module - any solution you come up with will likely do the the same things as a plugin and/or CPAN module except that since it's new code it won't be as mature and tested.

I've recently started using Dancer to develop a simple app and I'll describe how I'm solving this problem using CPAN modules. You may of course choose to ignore it.

My route handler for adding a user looks like this:

```
post '/user/add' => {
    my $args = valid_input('/user/add')
        or return template('user/add');
    my $user = User->new({
        username => $args->{username},
        # ...
    });
    user->insert;  # you'll probably want some error handling here
    set_flash('User added');
    redirect '/user';
};
```

The `valid_input` function is a helper I created for my app, which uses the [Data::Form::Validator](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-FormValidator) module from CPAN.  The `'/usr/add'` argument is the name of the validation profile to use - which for simplicity I decided to keep the same as the route name.

I won't bore you with the details of calling [Data::Form::Validator](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-FormValidator) since the documentation is pretty good.  What I will mention is that in the event that validation fails, the `valid_input` helper stores away the validation error messages for display in an alert box and also saves the submitted parameters:

```
my $q = params();  # need to force scalar context to get a hashref;
fill_in_form($q);  # save submitted parameters
```

I have a `before_template_render` hook that makes the saved validation error messages available to the template (they actually get rendered in `views/layouts/main.tt`).

I also have an `after_template_render` hook that takes the saved submitted parameters and puts them back into the rendered HTML form using the [HTML::FillInForm](https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-FillInForm) module.

Since I have that infrastructure in place, the route handler to display an existing user record in an edit form with all the fields pre-populated is trivial:

```
get '/user/:id' => sub {
    if( my $user = User->find( param('id') ) ) {
        fill_in_form($user);
        return template 'user/edit', { id => $user->id };
    }
    not_found "User not found";
};
```

The `User` in `User->find()` is another one of my app-specific helper functions.  It uses the [Dancer::Plugin::DBIC](https://metacpan.org/release/Dancer-Plugin-DBIC) module to return a resultset object for my `user` table.

I will say that I'm not necessarily a huge fan of Data::Form::Validator.  I have been able to achieve everything I wanted but sometimes it does seem to take more work than I'd like.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Well the reason why I wanted to avoid a cpan modules is that in Ruby it would take me 1 line per field e.g. email validation if self.email == ''
          errors << 'email cannot be blank'
        elsif !(email !=~ /\A\Z|\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i)
          errors << 'email must have a valid format'  is it really *that* complicate to do the same thing in perl e.g. another template, cpan module + separate file to define the validation criteria?  I just want to be sure I am not missing something as simple as in ruby... thanks

Comment: If you really think it's that easy in Ruby, then you can do it the exact same way in Perl.  Instead of `errors << 'message here'` in Perl you might say `add_error('message here')` and define the `add_error` helper function to push messages onto a global array.  Ultimately that's what Data::Form::Validator is doing, but in a more structured and reusable way (e.g.: it has a rule for email addresses so you don't need a regex). Also in my view it simplifies the logic to have one helper that returns a full set of valid input or nothing at all.

Comment: grant, thank you so much. If I am not asking too much and to the benefit of other future viewers could you refine your reply with a sample validation using data::validator as follow  (username, email, password, motivation) assuming username check should be existing, email the sytnax and existing, password matching 2 fields and motivation a certain length? I think it would be helfpful! If is too much asked I understand